# Partial Matching of name in a corpus to names in another column in a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, nlp

I have a dataframe like this

```py
                            Name                            Corpus
0  James Bond Junior Bristleback     Agent James Bond went missing
1            Batman Bin Superman      Superman saves the day again
2                  Thor S/O Odin  Loki was last seen in March 2020
```

I wish to get this output.

```py
                            Name                            Corpus  Value
0  James Bond Junior Bristleback     Agent James Bond went missing   True
1            Batman Bin Superman      Superman saves the day again   True
2                  Thor S/O Odin  Loki was last seen in March 2020  False
```

I have previously tried regex but it seems I can't get the desired output. Is there anyway to achieve this with regex or some other libraries/packages?

Comment: Do you just want to determine whether there are any common words between the two columns?

Comment: for instance if the word James Bond has a partial match to the first row in the name column, which is James Bond Junior Bristleback, it should return a True value

Comment: Should a sentence like "This is Bond James" match? What about "jAmeS bond"?

Comment: yes jAmes bond should match but not Bond James

Comment: Even in the context "he created a bond with James"? (Yes, text analysis is tricky)

Comment: Believe me, I once set up a filter with a specific set of characters on a mailserver, very unlikely to be in a legitimate email, and I realized that it blocked receiving a PDF file that had this particular string in its hex representation. Always expect the unexpected with text ;)

Comment: yeap. He created a bond with James will be False as well

Comment: @DDM then what about "this is Batman" or "this is Bond" this might be valid? Can you explicitly list the rules for match/non-match?

Comment: @mozway yes that will be valid. So long there is a substring in the corpus that matches the name it will return True.

Comment: Then there is no reason why "he created a bond with James" would be False ;) This means @ddejohn 's answer is what you want (you should probably accept it)

Comment: The sequence matters

Comment: Was your question answered? Please consider accepting the provided answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this exactly fits your needs. It essentially converts each sentence into a set of words, and checks if there is any overlap:

```py
df.Name.str.split().apply(set) & df.Corpus.str.split().apply(set)
```

Output:

```py
0     True
1     True
2    False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: I would have had a similar approach +1 ;)

Comment: Yeah this was my first instinct, however I have a feeling it might not be exactly what OP wants. It's a little hacky, tbh :D

Comment: Then OP should make the conditions more explicit ;)

Comment: Technically, without any condition `df['Value'] = [True, True, False]` is valid. I think your solution is more than fair :p